# Bootstrap 3 adding controls to a panel-heading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**Desired Outcome:**
Have a boot strap panel that contains a title on the left of the heading and a search text field with a addon button for a search.  The final icon would be an option/wrench button for setting some panel body options.

**Current Code:**

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">Panel header</h4>
                <div class="input-group pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current Result:**
I desire the panel-header to be on one line. I will do some adjustments as we go to smaller form size.  However the current code is causing the components to wrap onto multiple rows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just get rid of the `.pull-right` class in your input-group.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">Panel header</h4>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/Iu1IWlniGj)

**Update**

If you want the input (I gave it the ID `#Special`) smaller and right-aligned, you can do something like this via CSS:

```
#Special { 
    width: 200px; 
    float: right;
}
```

html:

```
<input id="Special" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

[Updated Example](http://www.bootply.com/wLqP6JHJLg)

Comment: You are correct remove the pull-right does collapse it to one line.  However the input text moves next to the title.  I want to move it to the right with the input-group-btn.  That is why I was trying the pull-right

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Actually I am looking at pushing the input to the right with the two buttons.  If you set the style it simply moves the text in the text field to the right.

Comment: Why did you never say so in the first place? I updated my answer again. I hope this time it is what you are looking for.